# Adding past transaction data to GA

Tags: google-analytics

I have problem with adding past transaction data to GA (360). Is it possible to do this, so that user's transaction date is the same in GA? I heard that I could do than via AMP, adding date as Custom Dimension, but I have to admit that I am a bit lost.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could populate a custom dimension with your transaction id in addition to the original [transaction id field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ti) , which you then use as key in a [Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191417?hl=en), using "Custom data" on "Query time", to have it available in the interface retrospectively.

When creating the custom dimension, you are free to use any scope of course. I would recommend hit scope in case a session can have multiple transactions.

Not sure what you mean with "AMP". Accelerated Mobile Pages, how can they help?

> I heard that I could do than via AMP, adding date as Custom Dimension

Comment: I meant Analytics Measure Protocol

Comment: ah, that makes more sense, my apologies.

That will not work for editing past transactions, as the hits have been processed/written already and can not be accessed retrospectively

If you would like to enrich current information with past transaction data, that should work. But I believe this was not your question, was it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the date in a custom dimension but this doesn't mean that Google Analytics assigns the transaction to the desired date (it is like assigning a label to the transaction but it will be acquired in Google Analytics on the sending date).

**Sending hits cannot be retroactive.**

Answer (score 0):

As an observation, to help you get a answer directly associated with your data collection, if you're using 360 then you should be able to request help from your certified partner - that's part of the value of using 360.